# what is the role of the word "evidencing" where I don't think evidencing is an adjective form for evidence if it works as verb why the writer add ing?

Tags: gerunds

What is the role of the word "evidencing" hereunder?

> In witness whereof, the above-mentioned shareholders have signed ***evidencing*** agreement.

Comment: The shareholders have signed the document, thereby **giving evidence** of their agreement.

Answer (score 1):

It is a present participle, a form of the verb that can act as a modifier.  Present participles end in "-ing"

The word "evidencing" modifies "agreement", and the expression could be paraphrased as "an agreement that evidences something". This seems to be a formal and technical legal term, not a common expression.

I think it should be "an evidencing agreement" or perhaps "the evidencing agreement".

The verb "evidence" is rare as a main verb, it is most often used as a participle, either a present participle or a past participle:

> Mozart's genius is evidenced by the lack of corrections in his manuscripts.

Comment: Or 'the signatures evidence the fact that the shareholders agree with [what the document says]'.